# ACTION didn't attach to reducer despite state of reducer in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I put logic of action for getting API DATA by AXIOS, then as dispatch method I tried to put received datas into state. But at this point actions didn't go to reducer.

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
index.js:23 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function
at index.js:23
```

Just I got that error above. This means this action did get a API data then when it try to dispatch, failed. I could find the connection point of this.

I attach some JavaScript:

reducer.js:

```
import * as types from '../Actions/Types';

const initialState = {
  contents: [{
    poster: 'https://i.imgur.com/633c18I.jpg',
    title: 'state title',
    overview: 'state overview',
    id: 123,
  }],
  content: {},
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOADING_DATA: {
      console.log(`something happend ${action.payload}`);
      return state.set('contents', action.payload);
    }

    case types.BTN_ON_CHANGE: {
      return state;
    }

    case types.BTN_ON_CLICK: {
      return state;
    }

    case types.BTN_ON_SUBMIT: {
      return state;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

actions.js

```
 import axios from 'axios';

import * as types from './Types';


const holder = [];
const API_GET = () => (
  axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=<<APIKEY>>&query=avengers+marvel')
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(data => console.log(data.results))
    .then(results => holder.add(results))
);

// export const loadingData = value => ({
//   type: types.LOADING_DATA,
//   value,
// });

export const loadingData = () => (dispatch) => {
  axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=54087469444eb8377d671f67b1b8595d&query=avengers+marvel')
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(data => console.log(data.results))
    .then(results => dispatch({
      type: types.LOADING_DATA,
      payload: results,
    }));
};

export const sample = () => (
  console.log('none')
);
```

LoadingDataButton.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { loadingData } from '../Actions';

const LoadingDataButton = props => (
  <div>
    <Button
      type="danger"
      onClick={
      props.loadingData()
    }
    >
            Loading
    </Button>
  </div>
);

LoadingDataButton.propTypes = {
  loadingData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  contents: state.contentR.contents,
});
const mapDispatchToState = {
  loadingData,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToState)(LoadingDataButton);
```

Comment: Are you saying that your action is not intercepted by your reducer?

Comment: Not related to the error you mention, but in your `loadingData` action you have a logging step (`.then(data => console.log(data.results))`). `console.log` returns undefined, so by putting that in the middle of your promise chain the next handler is putting undefined in the payload of the action. Does removing that line fix it?

Comment: You need to use proper middleWare for this

Comment: @ZaidCrouch i removed it as well but i've got same error,

Comment: As I said, didn't think it was related to the error you mentioned but it would have tripped you up sooner or later. Abinthaha's question is the right one though: have you definitely added the right middleware (looks like `redux-thunk` to your store)?

Comment: https://blog.benestudio.co/5-ways-to-connect-redux-actions-3f56af4009c8

Comment: @ZaidCrouch well i don't use any middleware yet once it worked, then i will turn it into redux-saga

Comment: Without middleware you can only dispatch plain objects as actions. Your `loadingData` action returns a function, you need some middleware to actually do anything with that.

Comment: @ZaidCrouch Thank you :) your advice helped me a lot! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your action creators return functions that perform the asynchronous requests, right now your action creators only return objects, we can return functions using [redux-thunk middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

Then you would write your action creators that make api calls like this

```
export const fetchThreadData = id => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_THREADS_REQUESTING,
    isLoading: true
  });

  const request = axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: "SOME API ADDRESS"
  });

  return request.then(
    response =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_THREADS_SUCCESSFUL,
        payload: response.data,
        isLoading: false
      }),
    error =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_THREADS_FAILED,
        payload: error || "Failed to fetch thread",
        isLoading: false
      })
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys who made a answer for my question, actually I solved this problem a quite easy way.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
// import saga from 'redux-saga';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const initialState = {};

const middleWare = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleWare),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  ),
);

export default store;
```

I planned to use SAGA after making this, but once I change middleware as thunk, it worked out well. Maybe I need to figure out how thunk works out.

Even if I prefer to use SAGA for this time I want to say thank you for Thunk.